# linux bash looping read from textfile with condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have file like this :

```
abc cde 3
abc def 2
abc rig 1
def rer 0
def ada 5
gia  dada 6
gia da 7
gia lla 9
```

and I want to read the file and looping only when the first column contain abc , the output is like this :

```
abc cde 3
abc def 2
abc rig 1
```

how can I do it in linux bash script?

i try to use while read but cannot done with condition

Comment: You have to search by yourself, then try something. If you were stuck, ask.   
Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Better use `awk` here. It's a very simple task for it. There's tons of examples here.